# beamer always creating PDFs with corrupted trailer dictionary

Tags: beamer, pdftex

I am trying to include a page of PDF generated using `beamer`. No matter what I try, I always end up getting an error that the PDF cannot be included since the “trailer dictionary” is missing.

> Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
>
> Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
>
> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./test.pdf): xpdf: reading PDF image failed
>
> ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

**MWE:** (ran using `pdflatex test.tex`)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A Frame}
  First
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A Second Frame}
  Second
  % Uncomment either of these after building the PDF
  %\includegraphics{\jobname.pdf}
  %\includepdf[pages={1,2}]{\jobname.pdf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is this a bug in `pdftex`, `beamer`, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You seem to be trying to recursively include the PDF in itself ...

Comment: Ah, I see! That’s a problem I now understand. Please convert you comment to an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you actually want to achieve!

Comment: I wanted to include parts of a PDF in its own document, like the “survey” option from `pdfpages`, but now realize that it’s required to rename the output file to include it in itself (like `slides-tmp.pdf` vs. `slides.pdf`).

Comment: It of course makes a lot of sense now. The PDF is of course half-way produced, when it’s trying to include the very same PDF document.